# Get results from Instagram API to use in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, instagram-api

I have been reading up on basic authentication on instagram for a client(app).  From what I gather on reading cURL is the best option most threads are saying.  I also found an Instagram PHP API wrapper on Gihub but I dont think I need to go that route to do what I need.

**What I am trying to do is this:**

A function checks the current users meta for 'instagram_user' (Instagram user ID) and 'instagram_token' (access token).

IF the usermeta is not set, meaning they have not authorized the client yet, it shows a link to the authorization url.  They click the link, authorize the app and return to our site.  I need to know how to retrieve this data once they return so I can use `add_user_meta` to save their token and ID to the `user_meta` tables.

```
//Get current user
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$instagram_userID = get_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_user', true);
$access_token = get_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_token', true);

if(!$access_token || !$instagram_userID){
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;">You need to authorize Instagram in order to see your feed here.</p><p><a class="btn btn-success" href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID-HERE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888&response_type=code" title="Click here to verify" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;">Verify Now</a>';
} else { //User is authorized ?>
<div id="user-instagram-feed"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)){
        var access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";   
        var user_id = "USER_ID";
        var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+user_id+"?access_token="+access_token+"&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $("#user-instagram-feed").append("<img src='"+data.data.profile_picture+"' />");
        });
    });
      </script>
<?php }
```

Where I get stuck is once the user authorizes the app and returns to our site, how to I get access the data object to pull the token and user id?

*Side note: This should not make a difference but the users feed will be in a widget on a buddypress install, so it will not always be the same users feed we are trying to display which is why we chose to save it to the database and run a conditional to see if it exists for the user.*

Comment: Out of interest; have you managed to get a single app approved (out of sandbox mode), and are now trying to use this app as a kind of blanket 'fetch anyones feed if they approve it' app? 

We are looking at how possible this is with the new guidelines, as getting a feed approved every time takes too long in an agency environment

Answer (score 1):

Is that mean you haven't getting your `instagram_user` and `instagram_token` value? Sorry, my English isn't that good.

This will actually need something like login with Instagram. Have you tried [Instagram PHP API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) library? Assuming your callback page is the same as the code you wrote (you should create custom callback page, though). So, it's basically like this.

**Note**: not tested. I never use this lib.

```
require '../src/Instagram.php';
use MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram;
if( !session_id() )session_start(); //check whether session isn't started

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
    'apiSecret'   => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'apiCallback' => 'YOUR_APP_CALLBACK' //this code's URL
));

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//Once user returned, get the token then store it (as you wish)
if (isset($_GET['code']){
$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
$token = $data->access_token;
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'instagram_token', $token);
}    

//Get current user
$access_token = get_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_token', true);
$instagram->setAccessToken($access_token);
$user_ig = $instagram->getUser();
$profile_picture = $user_ig->data->profile_picture;

if(!$access_token || !$instagram_userID){
    echo '<p style="text-align:center;">You need to authorize Instagram in order to see your feed here.</p><p><a class="btn btn-success" href="'.$instagram->getLoginUrl().'" title="Click here to verify" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;">Verify Now</a>';
} else { //User is authorized ?>
<div id="user-instagram-feed"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)){
            $("#user-instagram-feed").append("<img src='<?php echo $profile_picture; ?>' />");
    });
    </script>
<?php }
```

Comment: I was able to see a way to make it work from your answer, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chay22 I was able to get it to work.  I am posting the code below for others who may be searching for the same thing.

```
//Get current user & data
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            $instagram_userID = get_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_user', true);
            $access_token = get_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_token', true);
            $siteURL = site_url();

            //Instagram API calls
            if (isset($_GET['code'])){
                $code = $_GET['code'];

                //API params
                $apiData = array(
                  'client_id'       => '{CLIENT-ID-HERE}',
                  'client_secret'   => '{CLIENT-SECRET-HERE}',
                  'grant_type'      => 'authorization_code',
                  'redirect_uri'    => $siteURL,
                  'code'            => $code
                );

                $apiHost = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

                //cURL API request
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $user = json_decode($jsonData); 

                // If we have a toke and ID set it up in WP
                if($user->access_token) {
                    $instagram = $user->user;
                    add_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_token', $user->access_token, true);
                    add_user_meta($user_id, 'instagram_user', $instagram->id, true);
                    echo 'added meta';
                }
                //If error return error
                if($user->error_type && $user->error_message){
                    echo'<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: ' . $user->error_type . ' Error Message: ' . $user->error_message . '</div>';
                }
            }

            if(!$access_token || !$instagram_userID){
                //No token set yet

                echo '<p style="text-align:center;">You need to authorize Instagram in order to see your feed here.</p><p><a class="btn btn-success" href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={CLIENT-ID-HERE}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT-URI-HERE}&response_type=code" title="Click here to verify" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;">Verify Now</a></p>';

            } else { //User is authorized ?>

            <div id="user-instagram-feed"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    var access_token = "<?php echo $access_token; ?>";   
                    var user_id = "<?php echo $instagram_userID; ?>";

                    var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+access_token;
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        dataType:"jsonp",
                        url: url,

                        success: function(data){
                            var images = data.data[0].images;
                            //alert(images.standard_resolution.url);
                            $("#user-instagram-feed").append('<a href="' + data.data[0].link + '" target="_blank"><img src="'+images.standard_resolution.url + '" /></a>');
                        },
                        error: function (data, xhr, desc, err)
                        {
                            $("#user-instagram-feed").append('<div class="alert alert-danger">An Error Occurred: ' + xhr + ' ' + desc + ' ' + err + '</div>');
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
                  </script>
            <?php }
```

Cheers :)